# YouTube Player next prev buttons aren't visible for the first video

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to implement built-in YouTube player in my app (API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

I load more than one video id for playback (list of video IDs)

```
youTubePlayer.loadVideos(idList)
```

But when player starts prev and next buttons aren't available until the first video finishes and switches to the next one, only then buttons appears and I can switch between videos from my video list

[image]

Comment: have you got the answer?

Comment: @user2462737 no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started to work normally after some time

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you got the answer.... please lemme know

Comment: you better remove this answer and write it as comment